# Why is this mini program saying that the list index is out of range?

Tags: python, list, debugging

Why does this say list index out of range? This may not be the best way of doing this but just wondering why this is happening! Thanks

```
key = 13    

alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

replacement_set = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

count = -1

while count <= 25:
    count += 1
    if count < int(key):
        index_value = int(count + int(key))
        replacement_set[index_value] = alphabet[count]
        print replacement_set
    elif count >= int(key):     
        index_value = int(count - int(key))
        replacement_set[index_value] = alphabet[count]
        print replacement_set
    else:
            break

print replacement_set
```

Comment: You might want to replace the `while` with `for count in range[26]`. Then you don't have to manually update `count` (which is the root cause of your off-by-one error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simeon Visser's answer answers your question, but I think it's still worthwhile to point out the Pythonic solution to your problem:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as uppercase

replacement_set = uppercase[13:] + uppercase[:13]
```

`uppercase[:13]` is an example of slice notation. You can read more about it from [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: I switched this chunk out and into my code, but I found that it works without the whole first row. Why is that? I also wanted it to cycle the other way so I did replacement_set[27-key:] + replacement_set[:27-key] and that worked great! THANKS a million

Answer (score 4):

The `IndexError` happens here:

```
elif count >= int(key):     
    index_value = int(count - int(key))
    replacement_set[index_value] = alphabet[count] # <<<<<
```

and it happens because `count` has the value `26`. In other words, you're trying to access an element that's outside the bounds of `alphabet`. Note that your loop doesn't prevent this because you're adding `1` here:

```
while count <= 25:
    count += 1
```

In other words: when `count` is `25` you're still making it `26` by adding one. You can fix your code by turning that `while` line into:

```
while count < 25:
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but I don't quite understand. So how would I fix that?

Comment: @user2976947 I just added a proposed fix.

Answer (score 0):

That's why the error occurs:

```
while count <= 25:
    count += 1
    print count
```

End of Output:

```
24
25
26
```

...and alphabet[26] is out of range, because the key has to be lower than len(alphabet).

Use should use something like that:

```
key = 13
for count, letter in enumerate(alphabet):
    # calculate index_value, so it has to be in correct range
    index_value = (count - key) % len(alphabet)
    replacement_set[index_value] = letter
    print replacement_set
```

(more pythonic using `for`-loop and `enumerate`)